# How do I post a message my android application to Google Reader

Tags: android, google-reader

I have to post a message from my android app to Google Reader. How do I start to achieve this.
What is the supported API for this? Please tell me the procedure to achieve this.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajani Golakoti

Answer (score 0):

Please see my post to this simular question:

[How to integrate Google Reader in Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619013/how-to-integrate-google-reader-in-android-application/7236809#7236809)

and here is the unofficial API doc

http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI